# Is it possible to display on swagger documentation description from GitHub?

Tags: jenkins, github, .net-core, swagger

Is it possible to display on swagger documentation description from last commit on GitHub?

I'm using also Jenkins.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario in more details? Also, what do you mean by "Swagger documentation" - Swagger UI, or some other documentation renderer, or the actual Swagger YAML/JSON file?

Comment: I would like when I open Swagger UI, to see last commit.
somewhere on this page to be display (https://idratherbewriting.com/learnapidoc/images/swaggerpetstoreui.png)
I just want to know is that supported by swagger?

Comment: Which [version of Swagger UI](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/version-detection.md) do you use - 2.x or 3.x? Did you add Swagger UI manually (e.g. downloaded from the [repository](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/)), or is it generated by your source code framework (e.g. Swashbuckle or Springfox)?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean displaying the Swagger YAML/JSON file from the last commit, or displaying the actual commit message (e.g. "Added foo, fixed bar")?

Comment: Swagger UI is generated by Swashbuckle. thorough nugget.
I just want to display commit message. nothing more. So my other teammates could see what I commit last.